# Can we use gradient descent method in maximum entropy model?

Tags: machine-learning

I see a lot of implementations use GIS or IIS to train the maximum entropy model. Can we use gradient descent method? If we can use it, why most tutorial directly tell GIS or IIS method, but do not show the simple gradient desent method to train maximum entropy model? As we know, softmax regression is equivalent to the maxent model, but I never heard GIS or IIS in softmax. Why? Is there a toy code use simple gradient desent method to train maxent model? I think it's easy to implement a toy code, the derivation is simply compute the empirical expectation and model expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "maximum entropy model" is an ill-defined term, which can describe dozens of approaches which maximzie entropy. However, if you refer to the most well known "MaxEnt" then **it is just logistic regression**, which can and **is often** solved with gradient descent. Furthermore, classical feed forward networks use logistic regression cost (thus maximum entropy cost) in the last layer and they are solved with SGD as well.

To answer more generally - any model, which has a cost differentiable in parameters can be learned using GD. For example SVM can be learned with GD (even though usually it is not as we have more efficient methods which exploit some specific features of SVM).

Yet again "can be solved" does not mean "should be", as GD is very generic tool, which does not exploit problems characteristics (such as curvature etc.). Iterative scaling methods are simply more well-suited for a particular optimization problem of MaxEnt, as we know much more about MaxEnt cost that it is differentiable and has single solution.

See [Berkley lecture](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~klein/papers/maxent-tutorial-slides.pdf) for lots of details and step by step introduction to many of possible approaches.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helps me a lot. I just wondering most logistic regression tutorial will describe the gradient desent method but maxent model do not. It makes me confused that whether we can use gradient method in maxent model or not. From you answer and my thoughts, we can actually build a model use it, even though there are better methods.

Comment: Exactly. The differences also come from the fact that NLP and statistics optimization communities developed partially independently thus they do have their own "favorites".